# Creating an array of classes which extend a common base

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I have a number of classes, all of which extend class EntityManagerSystem().

i.e.

```
public class EntityManagerSystem
{
   public void init() {}
   public void update() {}
   public void free() {}
   public void reset() {}
}

public class AsteroidManager extends EntityManagerSystem...
public class TeleportManager extends EntityManagerSystem...

and so on.
```

I want to create an Array<>() holding these classes to make it easy to call the init(), update(), and free() methods within.

What is the best way to declare this array. I don't want to declare a [] array as the constructors for these classes have parameters, plus I need the flexibility of being able to add, and remove, entries.

Something like `Array<>() managerList...` I think, but I'm not sure of the correct declaration.

(I'm using LibGdx by the way...)

I've seen some posts which address *similar* questions, but they didn't really provide an answer i need.

TIA

Comment: I don't understand the question but it seems that `EntityManagerSystem` should be an `interface`

Comment: Just after some clarification on the following: Array to hold classes - Do you want to hold the class itself of the object instance? From my understanding you would want to use a List using the super type, e.g. List<EntityManagerSystem> list = new ArrayList<>();

Comment: The object of this exercise is to be able to use for( .. : .. ) to cycle through this list of managers, calling init(), update() etc, instead of having a long list of method calls. It seems I may be addressing this problem in entirely the wrong way,

Answer (score 0):

You can either make a List

`List<EntityManagerSystem> myList = new LinkedList<>();`

and then add your objects to that

`myList.add(new AsteroidManager(...));`

`myList.add(new TeleportManager(...));`

or if you insist in using an Array it works just like that too:

`EntityManagerSystem[] myThingies = new EntityManagerSystem[]{ 
   new AsteroidManager(...), 
   new TeleportManager(...) 
}`

Answer (score 0):

> I don't want to declare a [] array as the constructors for these classes have parameters

It is irrelevant whether the constructors have parameters. You declare arrays by specifying a type, not by specifying a constructor - that wouldn't make sense.

> plus I need the flexibility of being able to add, and remove, entries.

Then you need a collection class such as `ArrayList<EntityManagerSystem>`, instead of a [] array.

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare list of required objects: `List<EntityManagerSystem> instances = new ArrayList<>()`. It could be static as well. And then you have two options:

**First.** Manuall add new instance of `EntityManagerSystem` to this list after creation:

```
AsteroidManager asteroidManager = new AsteroidManager();
TeleportManager teleportManager = new TeleportManager();
instances.add(asteroidManager);
instances.add(teleportManager);
```

**Second** You can do it in the constructor of the base class:

```
abstract class EntityManagerSystem {

    protected EntityManagerSystem() {
        instances.add(this);
    }
}
```